# Is there any iOS implementation of the Bayeux protocol (COMET, server push to client)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, networking, server-push

Is there any library with implementation of the Bayeux protocol, for use in iOS (iPhone/iPad) development, for the building Server push technology iPhone client?

And what are your suggestion for doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Even though I haven't tried it, I would check FayeObjC:

"A simple Objective-C client library for the Faye publish-subscribe messaging server. FayeObjC is implementing on top of the zimt Objective-C web socket library and will work on both Mac and iPhone projects. JSON parsing is handled using the excellent JSONKit (github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) library which is included in the FayeObjC source folder."

For more info:
http://blog.cometcoast.com/post/3668374972/fayeobjc-an-objective-c-faye-client-for-ios-mac-os

Sources:
https://github.com/pcrawfor/FayeObjC

Comment: PLease be aware that the zimt Objective-C web socket is now out of date and no longer maintained. It miss something that is on the standard webSocket Protocol. I suggest to either wait for FayeObjc 2_0 release or checkout their 2_0 branch if you cannot wait. The webSocket library used in FayeObjC 2_0: SocketRocket which author is also the zimt's.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is fairly old, but I googled and found it. Maybe this answer can help someone else:

Take a look at ddunkin cometclient library: https://github.com/ddunkin/cometclient

I haven't tested but will try it with my next project.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use my reimplementation FayeClient with many additional stuff like blocks and error handling [MZFayeClient](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFayeClient)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fork of the DDunkin Comet client that supports ARC and client based subscription management which helps with resubscribing on disconnects.  I also added a lot of block support and delegate call backs.

https://github.com/yinzara/cometclient